# Twitch IRC chat bot successfully connects but does not detect commands

Tags: python, python-3.x, irc, twitch, chatbot

I started making a simple Twitch chat bot using Python. It connects fine, and it can also see the messages that other people are sending in the chat. My problem, however, is that I cannot seem to detect commands when they are used. I can grab the username and message of chat entries and even print them to the console, but passing them to the `chat()` function doesn't do anything.

Another quirk is that the bot will sometimes randomly send chat messages containing the PONG responses.

I think I am missing something obvious, perhaps with how I am checking for commands in chat, or my whole `chat()` function.

```
import re
from time import sleep
import socket


HOST = "irc.twitch.tv"
PORT = 6667
NICK = "bot_name"
PASS = "oauth:..."
CHAN = "#channel"
RATE = (20 / 30)
CHAT_MSG = re.compile(r"^:\w+!\w+@\w+\.tmi\.twitch\.tv PRIVMSG #\w+ :")


def main_loop():
    try:
        s = socket.socket()
        s.connect((HOST, PORT))
        s.send("PASS {}\r\n".format(PASS).encode("utf-8"))
        s.send("NICK {}\r\n".format(NICK).encode("utf-8"))
        s.send("JOIN {}\r\n".format(CHAN).encode("utf-8"))
        connected = True
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        connected = False

    while connected:
        response = s.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
        if response == "PING :tmi.twitch.tv\r\n":
            s.send("PONG :tmi.twitch.tv\r\n".encode())
            print("PONG")
        else:
            username = re.search(r"\w+", response).group(0)
            message = CHAT_MSG.sub("", response)

            if message == "!test":
                chat(s, "Testing command received!")

            print(username + ": " + message)
        sleep(1)


def chat(sock, msg):
    sock.send("PRIVMSG {} :{}".format(CHAN, msg).encode())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_loop()
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out the solution, if anyone else has the same problem! The message that is passed through the `chat()` function must have `\r\n` added to the end of the string and the command to check for would be `!test\r\n`. I am sure this is just the way in which IRC works, but this addition now lets the bot respond to commands!